# set select <option> as selected in form

Tags: php, html

I have a form wich inserts some data in a mysql database. 
This form contain a select and some options with their respective values like

```
<select name="car_type">
   <option value="sport">Sports car</option>
   <option value="van">Van</option>
   <option value="large">Large family sedan</option>
   <option value="small">Small city car</option>
</select>
```

The form can also be used to update a car's details in the database, it does so by loading the values from the database and fills the form automatically but I am stuck at making the `<option>` in the select, selected by default based on the value already set in the DB.
So if the user chooses to edit a car, lets say a car that already has Sports type filled in the DB, I want the form to automatically set the `<option value="sport">Sports car</option>` as selected, `<option selected="selected" value="sport">Sports car</option>`. By not doing this, the user has to choose again the type every time he submits the form, otherwise the first `<option>` and its value (sport) is sent by POST.

I am able to retrieve the value from the database by using $data['type'] but I did not find the exact php code to set the selected `<option>` to that in the database, can you guys help ?

Comment: pseudo code - if (something == something){$something = ' selected ' } else {$something = ''}

Comment: How do you generate the HTML for the individual option elements? The usual pattern is to loop to generate them, and in your case you would compare the existing DB value to the loop value and if they're equal, just add that bit of HTML (selected="selected").

Comment: Yes, I read that looping trough them with foreach it is the most common way, but I have them manually written in HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the code looks messy, you can do something like this:

```
<select name="car_type">
   <option value="sport" <?php if($data['type']=='sport') echo "selected='selected'"; ?> >Sports car</option>
   <option value="van" <?php if($data['type']=='van') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Van</option>
   <option value="large" <?php if($data['type']=='large') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Large family sedan</option>
   <option value="small" <?php if($data['type']=='small') echo "selected='selected'"; ?>>Small city car</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="large" <?php echo ($dbvalue=="large") ? "selected=\"selected\"" : "" ;?>>Large family sedan</option>
```

Work out the sql query bit yourself and replace my $dbvalue with the column data from your db

Comment: Or just `selected` instead of `selected="selected"` we're not in XHTML area anymore :-).

Comment: thought even html5 used selected="selected" ? must admit though all my apps are xhtml still so force of habit is to use that if just "selected" is valid html5 thats as good as :)

Comment: Yep it's valid HTML5 to write just `selected`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to mark the active car type I would do it like this:

```
foreach ($car_types as $car_type){
    echo '<option value="'.$car_type.'" '.($data['type']==$car_type?'selected':'').'>'.$car_type.'</option>';
}
```